# How do I convert sum of hex values back to hex values

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have an object containing a lot of hex values, which is:

```js
var perms = {
  // General
  generalCreateInstantInvite: 0x1,
  generalKickMembers: 0x2,
  generalBanMembers: 0x4,
  generalAdministrator: 0x8,
  generalManageChannels: 0x10,
  generalManageServer: 0x20,
  generalChangeNickname: 0x4000000,
  generalManageNicknames: 0x8000000,
  generalManageRoles: 0x10000000,
  generalManageWebhooks: 0x20000000,
  generalManageEmojis: 0x40000000,
  generalViewAuditLog: 0x80,
  // Text
  textAddReactions: 0x40,
  textReadMessages: 0x400,
  textSendMessages: 0x800,
  textSendTTSMessages: 0x1000,
  textManageMessages: 0x2000,
  textEmbedLinks: 0x4000,
  textAttachFiles: 0x8000,
  textReadMessageHistory: 0x10000,
  textMentionEveryone: 0x20000,
  textUseExternalEmojis: 0x40000,
  // Voice
  voiceViewChannel: 0x400,
  voiceConnect: 0x100000,
  voiceSpeak: 0x200000,
  voiceMuteMembers: 0x400000,
  voiceDeafenMembers: 0x800000,
  voiceMoveMembers: 0x1000000,
  voiceUseVAD: 0x2000000,
  voicePrioritySpeaker: 0x100
};
```

Those are permissions in the discord API. A role in Discord would have multiple permissions, and therefore, discord sums them together using `parseInt()` and converts them to decimal values (regular integer values) and store them in the classes of object.
For example, if the role has both `generalCreateInstantInvite` and
  `generalKickMembers`, the result of `role.permissions` would be `9` as it's the sum of `0x1` and `0x8`, and I know that because I know the role has those two specific permissions on them.

A quick summary:

1. I have a list of the perms in an object.
2. I have the sum of hex values of some of them.
3. I need to somehow convert the sum to the values themselves and put them in an array.

My question is, how do I make the bot that doesn't have any data else the permissions list (`perms`)and the permission integer (`9`) use them and output the permissions names (`generalCreateInstantInvite` and
  `generalKickMembers`) that they have? Or could there be an algorithm for that? If you have any links that might help, please send them.

Main JavaScript file example:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const perms = require('./Storage/perms.js');

bot.on('message', (message) => {
  let prefix = '/';
  let sender = message.author;
  let msg = message.content;
  let cont = msg.split(' ');
  let args = cont.slice(1);
  let cmd = msg.startsWith(prefix) ? cont[0].slice(prefix.length).toUpperCase() : undefined;

  if (cmd === 'GETPERMISSIONS') {
    let role = message.guild.roles.get(args[0]); // args[0] should be role ID
    let rolePerms = role.permissions; // rolePerms is sum of hex values

    // Converting back the hex sum to permission names and place in an array...

    message.channel.send(permNames.join(' - '));
    return;
  }
});
```

Comment: Iterate over the properties of `perms` and store the property if the corresponding flag is set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use discord.js to convert it by using [`Permisions#toArray`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=toArray)
Used like this:

```
new Discord.Permissions(role.permissions).toArray();
```

if the role has no permissions it will give an empty array `[]`
otherwise it will give an array filled with [`Permissions#FLAGS`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS)

```
[ 'KICK_MEMBERS',
  'BAN_MEMBERS',
  'MANAGE_CHANNELS',
  'MANAGE_GUILD'
]
```

You can obviously also use the other functions of the [`Permissions Class.`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions)